# Smart Card Pass Cert Updated, will no longer pass to VM

Tags: smartcard, remote-desktop, vmware-workstation, juniper-network-connect

I tried to search around but couldn't find a solution to my issue.  I've been passing through a smart card to my VM for a few years without issue.  I get on my VM, go to the URL of my Juniper VPN, type my username and password and click connect.  In the past it has presented me with the smart card's certificate, but since I've updated the cert on my card (it expired), it will no longer present it.  I can use this card directly from my laptop or from another VM without issue.  Here are the steps I've tried to resolved this unsuccessfully:

1.Cleared browser cache, closed browser, opened and tried
2.Opened mmc certificates snap-in and removed all personal certificates
3.Cleared all Juniper ActiveX controls from: Internet Options/Browser History Settings/View Objects/Juniper* (deleted)
4.Uninstall all Juniper programs
5.Deleted all certs on VM with:  certutil -scinfo

When I look in IE for certificates, I don't see the new one on there but continue to see the old ones.  If I clear them, they go away until the next time I recycle the VM, then they show up again.

Note that the certutil -scinfo command had me enter the pin on my smart card 3 times so it seems to see it.  That command also returned successful.  Also note that I am not the first person to have this issue in my organization.  Another had it when he got the certificate updated on his smart card.  He gave up and created a new VM.  I'm not really hip to doing that because it would take me a few weeks to set up the VM how I need it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me on this issue!  Eric﻿

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of trouble shooting, I've come to the conclusion that this is an issue in Remote Desktop.  Somehow Remote Desktop is caching my old certificat